# SQL - Schemas - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in a new job using Microsoft SQL Server.
Is there a way to show how all of these tables link together?

Comment: Which tables link together?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/work-with-database-diagrams-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Kat; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course,

Go to Database > Database Diagrams > New Database Diagram
Then add all the tables.

This diagram shows you all the tables and relationships.